Can a subgroup be covered by a non-conjugate subgroup?
I have an elementary group theory question that I feel should be standard to answer, but I haven't found any solution. It is as follows:

Given a finite group $G$ and two non-conjugate subgroups $H, K$ of the same order, does there exist an element $h \in H$ such that for all $g \in G$, $h \not\in {}^gK$ (or vice versa)? I'm specifically interested in the case where $G$ is a finite $p$-group.

(Edit: I should have been more precise - I want that either there exists an element $h \in H$ such that for all $g \in G$, $h \not\in {}^gK$ or there exists an element $k \in K$ such that for all $g\in G$, $k \not\in {}^gH$.)
The motivation for this is representation-theoretic: I'd like to determine if the Borel-Smith functions detect nonconjugacy: that is, given two non-conjugate subgroups $H, K$ of $G$ (not necessarily of the same order anymore), there exists a Borel-Smith function $f$ for which $f(H) \neq f(K)$. A positive answer for the above question can be used to show this, but a direct proof would be nice.

The answer is no, and the smallest counterexamples have $|G| = 24$.
For example take $G = S_4$, $H = \langle (12)(34), (13)(24) \rangle$ and $K = \langle (1234) \rangle$. Then $|H| = |K| = 4$ but $H \subseteq \cup_{g \in G} K^g$.
You can find an example with $H \cong K \cong C_2 \times C_2$ in $G = C_2 \times A_4$.
Search with GAP or Magma you can find many more examples, and also among $p$-groups.
For example you can take $G = SmallGroup(32,43)$, which is a semidirect product $G = C_8 \rtimes (C_2 \times C_2)$, with $C_2 \times C_2$ acting faithfully on $C_8$. Then you can find subgroups $H \cong K \cong C_2 \times C_2$ such that $H \subseteq \cup_{g \in G} K^g$.
In fact in this example $\cup_{g \in G} H^g = \cup_{g \in G} K^g$.

I should have been more precise with my question - I actually want that property holds for either $H,K$ or $K,H$; in the $S_4$ example, it holds for $H$ and $K$ as listed, but not with the subgroups swapped. However this does answer the question as stated, thank you! I suspect that even my stronger question is false, but it might take a larger group to find an answer.

So you want an example with $\cup_{g \in G} H^g = \cup_{g \in G} K^g$? I think the $SmallGroup(32,43)$ example should work.

Perfect, thank you!
